# Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f(x) = f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Show that if $f$ is bounded function on $[0;1]$ and satisfying
>   $$f(ax) = b f(x)$$
>   with $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{a}$ and $a,b > 1$ then
>   $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f(x) = f(0)$$

**Solution:**
There is exist  $M \geq 0$ such that $|f(x)| \geq M$ with $x \in (0;1)$. From $f(ax) = b f(x)$, $x \in [0;\frac{1}{a}]$ implies $f(a^2 x) = b^2 f(x)$ with $x \in [0;\frac{1}{a^2}]$. Use induction on $n$, we have
$$f(a^n x) = b^n f(x),\quad with \quad x \in \left[0;\frac{1}{a^n}\right], n \in \mathbb{N}$$
So,
$$|f(x)| \leq M \frac{1}{b^n}, \quad with \quad x \in \left[0; \frac{1}{a^n}\right], n \in \mathbb{N} \qquad (*)$$
Other way, from $f(ax) = bf(x)$ implies $f(0)=0$. Associate with $(*)$ we have Q.E.D.

I do not understand why we conclude that $|f(x)| \leq M \frac{1}{b^n}$ after use the induction. Could you explain this to me. Thanks all!

Comment: There exists $M \ge 0$ such that $\lvert f(x) \rvert {\color{red}\le} M$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: I have a similar idea with you. This solution have some error.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, $f(a^nx) = b^n f(x)$ with $x \in [0, 1/a^n]$. So you can also write $f(x) = \frac{f(a^nx)}{b^n}$, and then by upper bounding $f(a^nx) \leq M$ you get your result, i.e. :
$$|f(x)| = \left|\frac{f(a^nx)}{b^n}\right| = \frac{ \left|f(a^nx)\right|}{b^n} \leq \frac{M}{b^n}$$